# Ankhsvn integration with Visual Studio 2010 - Adding Solution - Working Folders Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

Newb to Ankhsvn and Ubersvn integration.

I have existing web projects built in Visual Studio 2010 and am attempting to add them into a newly created repositories. The issue I'm having is trying to configure the working local directory. I've got my projects contained in various folders on my machine but it seems Ankhsvn will not let you change the "Local Folder" (which I'm assuming is the working folder) on your machine, it only gives selected options in a dropdown. I know Visual Studio generates it's own solution file in the standard directories (my docs../vis stud../projects/...) but that is not my working directory which it seems Ankhsvn is fixed in.

I don't want to have to move my projects around (and probably don't have enough space on my c: drive anyway). Does someone have any insight on how I can configure the local folders ankhsvn and Ubersvn can work out of?

Using Windows 7 64bit if that has any bearing as well. Our svn repository is hosted externally.

**UPDATE**

Well I haven't heard any feedback yet on this so I basically went ahead and used the following methodology to get my files into the repository:

1) Used TortoiseSVN to add the files to the svn repository (with TortoiseSVN installed, right click on the folder you want to add, TortoiseSVN -> Import and basically add in the repository URL ad go about adding in folders and files as desired.

2) next step was to then open Visual Studio 2010 and open the given web project folder and then go File -> Subversion -> Open project from subversion. NOTE: make sure when you open that you select the correct folder to import to. It should be one level above the given folder you selected.

3) after the import, all my files appeared as in conflict. I basically just commited the files and the issue went away.

So I now have my project hooked into svn and working through Ankhsvn but has to use TortoiseSVN to get it done...hmmm

Comment: +1 For following up with an explanation of what you did. I'm having a nightmare with AnkhSVN!!

Comment: @engineer...curious on your edits...can you explain why the selected removals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To administer the repository in uberSVN you need to make it aware of the repository. The easiest way to do this is to *create* the repository within the uberSVN admin page, but you've already done that bit, so we need to make uberSVN aware of it.

To do this:

- Create a Dump file based on your manually created repository
- Login to uberSVN as an System Admin or Repository Admin
- Click on Repositories
- Click on Add
- Enter a Repository Name (which will enter a Location automatically)
- Click Next
- Click Import From Uploaded Dump File or Import From Dump File Located On The Server
- Select the Dump file in question
- Click Done

Your repo will now be brought underneath uberSVN, loaded into a newly created Repo sat in the /uberSVN/repositories storage location.

From there you just continue as normal with your preferred subversion client.

Answer (score 0):

Know this QA is old but thought worth updating.
Got a solid, reproducable method for adding projects into remote UberSVN repository from Visual Studio 2010...trial and repeat seems to work consistantly on my side. Here goes

- Go to remote UberSVN server, Login
- Create Repository

> "Your Repository Name"

- Added users to repository
- Created Visual Studio project (File -> New Project) in similar ubersvn structure…in this case
              In windows explorer, created folders D:\\\trunk\
- In Visual Studio, create new project, uncheck “Create directory for solution” and I set the “Name” to

> "Your Project Name"

- In the first solution and subversion create phase, I checked off “Add to Subversion”
- Created project and the subversion repository selection popup came up.
- typed in the new repository url

> http://"your UberSVN Repository URL"/"Your Repository Name"/

- Below the Repository URL, I selected the repository “Database” image and then I clicked “Create Folder”

**NOTE**: When I did again, it seemed that there was already a “trunk”, ”branches” and “tags” folders generated under the repository database -> I clicked on the trunk folder).

- If the folders from above notes do not exist, I typed in “trunk” as new folder and then the proper Project url appeared in the “Project will be created in:” section at the bottom of the popup (

> http://"your UberSVN Repository URL"/"Your Repository
>   Name"/trunk/"Your Project Name"/

)

- Clicked OK
- Started copying files from existing website/project to new project
- Once all files are in and no more errors exist, start to do initial commits

**Visual Studio 2010 NOTES**:

- May have to regenerate designer files from older visual studio 2008 projects. Right click on the web form page you want to convert to “Web Application” and it will autogenerate the designer file for the given webform (web page)
- Will have to add in references from the bin folder for any dlls needed in project
- If bringing over classes from another project (i.e. in App_Code folder), need to right click on each (or select multiple) and go to properties -> Build Action and change from “Content” to “Compile”